How to export ActiveCollab project?
I was working with a service provider for more than a year with the project managed entirely within ActiveCollab Cloud. Now that the service agreement is over, they are not allowing us to continue to have access to our project.
They are willing to export it, but can't identify a method to do this with the current version. Apparently it was possible years ago, but that "legacy" support is no longer available.
What are my options? Perhaps each task can be saved and downloaded in some way? Perhaps there's a plugin or some kind of extension or service that can be used to connect to the service to do this? Perhaps the AC API can be used?
